# How to use arara with TeXShop

Tags: compiling, automation, texshop, arara

I try to use `arara` with TeXShop on my Mac, but I don't understand some steps either javascript, probably because of my english & my programer level.

I create first the arara.engine in the /Engines folder :

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH} 
arara "$1"
```

I use Tex Live Utility, & the package `arara` exists. OK.

I install the `arara-3.0-installer.jar` with the cross-platform installer. Ok.

I put all files from sources in my computer. Ok.
But I don't agree the step with Apache Maven, it just seemed too complicated… & isn't it to program complicated things ? :( So !

I choose the compilation mode `arara` & I just put in preamble :

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: xelatex -shell-escape
% arara: xelatex
```

& nothing. What I missed ?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is already an `arara` engine in TeXShop, and `arara` is already installed as part of TeXLive.  Move the `arara` engine from the `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/Inactive` folder to the `Engines` folder itself.  Then restart TeXShop.

In your document add the line:

```
% !TEX TS-program = arara
```

in addition to your `arara` lines and things should just work.

You can get TeXShop to add this line for you by using the Program choice in the Macros menu.

(Or choose the `arara` engine from the dropdown menu next to the Typeset button)

**Note** If you have created your own engine, you need to make sure the executable bit is set. To do this, use the Terminal and use the following command (assuming you have named the engine `myarara.engine`:

```
 chmod +x ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/myarara.engine
```

You shouldn't have to do this if you are using the preinstalled `arara` engine.

Comment: I haven't restart TeXShop, but now he said: - /Users/~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/arara.engine has no active execution bit - Now I have to configure this engine file, isn't it ?

Comment: So I don't need this program arara-3.0-installer.jar and using Maven… Ok

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to use the installer at all. And if you use the pre-installed `arara` engine, this error shouldn't arise.  For the engine you created, you need to set the executable bit on the file.  In a Terminal window you need to do `chmod +x ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/arara.engine`.

Comment: It is a success ! Thank you for this lesson ;) I lost a day trying to understand something simple. Thanks

Comment: Hi Alan , I need some help on glossary creation.I have also tried to install arara. I can see a drop down menu arara on my TeXshop. However I could not perform a makeglossaries command on arara prompt. Please advise.

Comment: Alan, can you just add the `chmod` part to your answer?

Comment: @kando I've added a note about that. For the default `arara` engine, I don't think it should be needed.

Comment: (I mention this because I just had to do it on my fresh installation ; j ) After moving the `arara` engine out of Inactive and attempting to run it (restarted the app first and all), I kept getting the error: `does not have the executable bit set`. `chmod` was the fix : j