# How do I pass gs options to simpdftex?

Tags: texshop, ps2pdf

Call me crazy, but I write my own figures in postscript, and my figure files need to access the file system (because I have files full of routines that the figure files use).

Because postscript can be a security hazard, the default for ghostscript is to disallow access to the file system, so my files can't be processed in ghostscript (and thus in ps2pdf).  No problem, there is a -dNOSAFER option for gs and p2spdf, so

ps2pdf -dNOSAFER figure.ps

works.  I write .tex in TeXShop, which uses simpdftex to do latex, dvips, ps2pdf.  So I need to figure out how to pass -dNOSAFER through simpdftex to ps2pdf.  Simple things I have tried, like passing the option

--distiller "ps2pdf13 -dNOSAFER"

to simpdftex don't seem to work.

Thanks,

Nathan

P.S.  To keep you from wasting your time on unhelpful answers, I know about the package epstopdf which can automatically run ps2pdf on each figure file when I run pdflatex, and that works nicely for almost all situations, but sometimes I really need to mess with .ps in a way that pdftex/epstopdf can't handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try `arara` instead of `simpdftex`. Here's an example (file `reading.tex`, where `polarcircle.eps` is an EPS file I have in my testing directory):

```
% !TEX TS-program = Arara
% arara: latex
% arara: dvips
% arara: ps2pdf: { options: '-dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 -dNOSAFER' }

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Some text

\includegraphics[width=4cm]{polarcircle.eps}

\end{document}
```

There's an `arara` engine for TeXShop that you may have to enable, just like for any alternative engine. See [How to use arara with TeXShop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175671/how-to-use-arara-with-texshop) for enabling the engine. Once you have enabled it, just hit Command-T and `arara` will be run due to the `!TEX TS-program` line.

Hitting Command-T or running

```
arara -v reading
```

from the terminal and `pdfinfo reading.pdf` shows the following information:

```
Title:          reading.dvi
Creator:        dvips(k) 5.995 Copyright 2015 Radical Eye Software
Producer:       GPL Ghostscript 9.16
CreationDate:   Fri Aug 21 22:40:31 2015
ModDate:        Fri Aug 21 22:40:31 2015
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      595 x 842 pts (A4)
Page rot:       0
File size:      8348 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.3
```

If called with `arara --log -v reading`, an `arara.log` file is created, which contains the following lines:

```
21 Aug 2015 22:40:31.189 TRACE CommandTrigger - Command: latex      "reading.tex"

21 Aug 2015 22:40:31.406 TRACE CommandTrigger - Command: dvips "reading.dvi" -o "reading.ps" 

21 Aug 2015 22:40:31.615 TRACE CommandTrigger - Command: ps2pdf -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 -dNOSAFER "reading.ps" "reading.pdf"
```

showing that the system calls are exactly what you need.