# Mac Texshop - How to Use Arara (Potential Bug)

Tags: mac, texshop, debugging, arara, bugs

This question was asked [previously](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175671/how-to-use-arara-with-texshop); however,
it was not answered for my issues.

I correctly:

- Copied the `arara.engine` file from `.\Engines\Inactive\` to `.\Engines`.
- Used the Macro\Program pulldown to insert the `% !TEX TS-program = arara` line.

Still, `arara` fails when using `lmkclean` or `bibtex`:

```
% !TEX TS-program = arara
% !arara: lmkclean
% !arara: pdflatex: {   draft: yes, options: '-file-line-error -halt-on-error' }
% !arara: bibtex
%  arara: pdflatex: {   draft: yes, options: '-file-line-error -halt-on-error' }
%  arara: pdflatex: { synctex: yes, options: '-file-line-error -halt-on-error' }
% !arara: lmkclean
```

Note that removal of the `!` in front of `lmkclean`, `pdflatex` and/or `bibtex` uncomments these lines.

### lmkclean fail:

```
Running LaTeXmKCleaner... 

Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 19 Jan. 2017, version: 4.52c.

------------
Latexmk: Could not find file ["2016.02.08 Kando Proposal.tex"].
-- Use the -f option to force complete processing.
FAILURE
```

### bibtex fail:

```
Running BibTeX... 

I couldn't open file name `"2016.02.08 Kando Proposal.aux".aux'
FAILURE
```

Note the repeated extension.
I think there is a **bug** at play here.

Comment: Hello! `:)` It is sort of a bug, indeed (technically, it is more of a bad decision on my part back then). The reason of this issue is the space in the filename. The new version in development (version 4.0, namely) addresses this issues and this odd behaviour is no more, but I am still stuck in the user manual writing due to some priorities at the moment (my thesis). Two workarounds are possible: (a) remove the spaces in the filename, or (b) stick with `latexmk` for some time. I sincerely apologize for the incovenience. `:(`

Answer (score 5):

Although this is conceivably a bug, its cause is quite clear: you have created a filename that is almost guaranteed to confuse most command line programs, since you have multiple `.` and spaces.

If you rename your file to something more sensible, the problem will go away:

```
2016-02-08_Kando_Proposal.tex
```

will work just fine.

In this case it's the spaces that are the problem, not the `.`s.  This may be an interaction between `latexmk` and `arara` (depending on how `arara` passes filenames to `latexmk`).

Comment: Bingo, you are absolutely spot on, Alan! I am aware of this, and it is fixed in version 4.0 (in development). But there is the thesis... so the new version is a bit behind the schedule...

Comment: @PauloCereda if `arara` is doing its own quoting of filenames, then this is the source of the problem, but as a quick fix I think you can configure `latexmk` not to to filename quoting I think.

Comment: `arara` is surely the one to blame here. It was a bad decision of my part to make the underlying OS handling method to guess quoting, and that's why we had so many problems...