# Using TeXShop, how to automatically compile twice or more

Tags: compiling, texshop

You all know the feeling when needing to compile twice before the desired output has been achieved.

I am using TeXShop and am a bit tired of clicking on the **Typeset**-button, waiting for everything to compile, and then clicking on the **Typeset**-button again, to wait for a second compilation ...

Any solution so as to make TeXShop compile two or more times automatically please?

Comment: Define a new command that calls pdflatex twice. Or use a tool like arara or latexmk

Comment: why would you ever want to do this?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle To save time.

Comment: making everything take twice as long does not save time.

Comment: the normal cycle is that you write some words, run latex, some ref may be ? but it doesn't matter. write some more words run latex again the refs resolve to [3] or whatever. write some more words, run latex....  running latex twice at each step just makes the typesetting stage take twice as long and has no advantages

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It actually can have an advantage. I am working with a code that, whenever I alter a bit of text, almost the whole page will become unreadable after one time compiling, but will be perfectly readable after two times compiling. This is because certain (and very many) tooltips are involved, which are not placed where they should be placed (after one compilation).

Comment: perhaps I should have said almost never any use. It seems surprising that it's necessary (for example your tex code could probably spot that the position information is not available and not output them at all rather than output them in the wrong place) but anyway my comment was really to your opening "You all know the feeling "  as no I think most people do not know that feeling (or should not know that)   If you have a very special document with custom requirements you may need this in those special circumstances, but this is far from being a general issue.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. Coincidentally, I just happened to have asked a [new question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394524/whats-so-special-about-and-～) in which you can see what sort of visual problems can occur if you compile only once (although not the main topic of that question though). One needs to modify the code a bit: it becomes apparent if one copies the line starting with `\Chinese{疊。。【疊` about twenty or more times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file similar to the following named `MyPdfLatex.engine` in the directory `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/` and make it executable via `chmod +x MyPdfLatex.engine`:

```
#!/bin/sh
bfname="$1"
pdflatex  --file-line-error --shell-escape  -recorder --synctex=1 "\input{$bfname}"
pdflatex  --file-line-error --shell-escape  -recorder --synctex=1 "\input{$bfname}"
```

You should customize the `pdflatex` command line above for your particular case.  Then, upon next restart of TeXShop, select `MyPdfLatex` instead of `LaTeX`. Then, when you `Typeset` and you sill see it compile twice.

If you want the pulldown engine to default to `MyPdfLatex`, go to `Preferences/Typesetting` panel and set the *Default Command* to `MyPdfLatex`.

Comment: Have you confirmed that this works when simply changing the two instances of `pdflatex` into `lualatex` as well please? I can't get it to work just yet.

Comment: I have figured it out now. Just copied everything from `LuaLaTeX.engine` and copied the last line twice.

Answer (score 4):

The best tool for this particular case (which wasn't obvious from your initial question) would to use the TeXShop `arara` engine and use `arara` rules to compile the file.

See:

- [How to use arara with TeXShop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175671/2693)

In this case you can simply put the following lines at the top of your document:

```
% !TEX TS-program = arara
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex { synctex: true }
```

The first line tells TeXShop to use the `arara` engine, and the next two lines tell `arara` to process the file twice. Since results of  the first compilation will never be viewed `pdflatex` can be run with no options; on the second run, the `synctex` option is added so that you have synchronization between source and preview.  Obviously you can adjust the tool to run `lualatex` or `xelatex`, etc. if that's the engine you are using.

For other use cases (particularly resolving citations and references), the `latexmk` approach is very helpful.

TeXShop comes with a `pdflatexmk` engine which will compile your document (and also run `bibtex` or `biber` and other tools) as many times as is required, but not more.

This is better than blindly requiring the document to be compiled twice.  The easiest way to use it is to add:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
```

to the first line of your document.  There are other versions for different engines (`xelatexmk`, `lualatexmk`, etc.)

If the engine doesn't show up in the pulldown Typeset menu, then you need to move it from the `Inactive` folder to the `Engines` folder within `~/Library/TeXShop`.

See:

- [When and why should I use % !TEX TS-program and % !TEX encoding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78101/2693)

Of course the two approaches can be combined, so if you are using `arara` you could have the first compilation be plain `pdflatex` and the second compilation use `latexmk` and have the best of both worlds:

```
% !TEX TS-program = arara
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatexmk { synctex: true }
```

Comment: So, how many times will this "compile"?

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen `latexmk` will compile as many times as needed to fully resolve references and bibliography citations.  It's not a fixed number of times, but as many as is required.  For `arara` you tell it within each document the actual compilations you want  by adding one `arara` directive line per compilation.

Comment: I have inserted `% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk` at the top of my document, yet I still have to manually compile **twice** to get the desired result. Nothing related to references or bibliographies though.

Comment: Also, to make the answer complete, you have mentioned that the **arara** engine could also be used, so then could you also specify which arara-rules should then be used please?

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen It wasn't clear from your question why you wanted the two compilations. For your particular use case, the `arara` solution is probably better.  I've updated the answer.